# Check joomla defalut password is mix or not

Tags: joomla, passwords, joomla2.5

I want check joomla default password is mix or not actually i want in joomla registration when user enter password then it must be 4 characters and 2 numeric . how i do this in joomla 2.5. I have checked in validate,js file also . but in this file only for increase password string not check mix password. so how i do that.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla doesn't have this in its standard package.

The best place to look would be the [Password Management](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/password-management) section the Joomla Extension Directory, it looks like it has a few solutions in it.